# creating a category list using linq

Tags: .net, linq

I have the following List which contains the following collection.

How i can transform this with linq so that i get nested items.

```
 var categories = new List<Category>(); // id, parentId, name
        categories.Add(1, 0, "Sport");
        categories.Add(2, 0, "Pets");
        categories.Add(3, 1, "Foot ball");
        categories.Add(4, 2, "Cat");
        categories.Add(5, 3, "Pele");
        categories.Add(6, 4, "whiskers");
        // ie Pets - > Cat - > Whiskers





   public class Category
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ParentId { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Your question.  It makes no sense.  Also virtual properties are weird.

Comment: Shouldn't the id's of the ParentID be different? e.g. Cat and Whiskers are ID 1 and "Foot ball" and Pele are 2 that way you can group them?

Comment: What do you want as output? What is your constructor for Category? (As I see it, the `Add` method calls will fail...)

Comment: Why do you need to transform it? Just query the relevant IDs when you need to extract results.

Comment: oops, i;ve fixed my example. should make sense now. I've removed the virtual ( was from Nhibernate, but not needed for this example)

Comment: This example make no sense, fisrt of all this do not compile. and why every Category have all otherone categories, and where is the string 3rd field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
        var nested = categories.GroupBy(c => c.ParentId)
                               .Select(cat => new Category
                               {
                                   ParentId =  cat.Key,
                                   Categories = cat.Select(x => new Category
                                                                    {
                                                                        Id = x.Id
                                                                    }).ToList()
                               });
```

I did something similar and works but with two levels, if you need something more generic and with multiple levels I'm not sure if you can do it with LINQ at least.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it.
(edit, corrected for orphans, and returning all roots)

```
List<Category> results = new List<Category>();
Dictionary quickCategories = categories.ToDictionary(c => c.ID);

foreach(var g in categories.GroupBy(c => c.ParentID))
{
  if quickCategories.ContainsKey(g.Key)
  {
    quickCategories[g.Key].Categories = g.ToList();
  }
  else
  {
    results.AddRange(g);
  }
}
```

Comment: hey thanks, i tried the first, but it seems ParentId is not the dictionary. ALso i tried the second, but how do i return a value from this?